# Google map geocoder throws "c is undefined" error (and other errors) only when Firebug is open

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebug, google-geocoder

I am using Google's geocoder webservice, and I often get the following JavaScript error: `c is undefined`.  My script is very simple and shown below.  I've since found that the error only occurs when using Firefox, and furthermore, only when the Firebug console is open.  Why does this happen and how do I prevent it (other than just closing Firebug).

```
var geocoder=new google.maps.Geocoder;
geocoder.geocode({address: '123 Main Street, Seattle WA 98123'},function(GeocoderResult, GeocoderStatus) {});
```

I have also experienced other errors when firebug is open.  For instance, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple throws `JSON.parse: unexpected character` error when firebug is open.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your posted code.

Comment: @geocodezip.  Yes, I noticed that and fixed it.  It was not the cause of the `c is undefined` error.

Comment: What version of Firebug are you using? And do you have any extension for Firebug installed ?

Comment: @fflorent.  Firebug 1.12.1b1.  I don't have any Firebug extensions installed.

Comment: Could you install the last version of Firebug (1.12.2, released some days ago), and test again?
If that doesn't help, could you please post a topic on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebug with exact steps to reproduce, and post the link here (it might be a Firebug bug)